# How do I fix this IndexOutOfBoundsException even though my program is giving me the result i want?

Tags: java

I made a small little program that picks a given word out randomly then shuffles it. The program is giving me the right results, but i get an IndexOutOfBoundsException. How do I fix it. I think the problem is downward from line 16 and on.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Scramble {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      String[] words= {"hat", "bubble", "camcorder"};
      Random rand = new Random();
      int endNum = rand.nextInt(3);
      for (int i=0;i<=endNum;i++) {
         int alt = endNum;
         if (alt==0 || alt ==1 || alt==2) {
            String ChosenWord=words[alt];
            LinkedList<Character> lnk = new LinkedList<Character>();
            for (int j=0;j<=ChosenWord.length()-1;j++) {
               lnk.add(ChosenWord.charAt(j));
            }
            Collections.shuffle(lnk);
            for (int p=0;p<=lnk.size();p++) {
               char addLet=lnk.get(p);
               String wholeWord=""+addLet;
               System.out.print(wholeWord);
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please... Believe it or not but one day when someone will judge your code (teacher, interviewer or fellow programmer) such a chaotic indentation will immediately make you a terrible or negligent programmer to their eyes

Comment: i had to eat dinner and was in a rush. If there is like some auto indentation shortcut, id be glad to use it.

Comment: There isn't, but if your code is indented in your IDE it will be indented here.

Answer (score 2):

Java collections and arrays are indexed 0 - the size - 1. You're having the loop go from 0 - the size of the collection which causes an out of bounds exception.

Change this loop from this.

```
for (int p=0;p<=lnk.size();p++)
```

To this

```
for (int p=0;p<lnk.size();p++)
```

**EDIT**

Remove this loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<=endNum;i++)
```

Or else you'll shuffle two words of 'bubble' and three words of 'camcorder'.

Comment: Or just `for (char c: lnk)`

Comment: If i do that my program ends up scambling the word up twice. So for example the word "bubble" becomes "lbbebueblbbu"

Comment: @JohnJay That's because of the first loop you have. You don't need the first loop. Let's say you random number `endNum` is 2. This means the chosen word will be bubble. This also means that this whole cycle will happen twice, meaning it'll shuffle the word bubble x2. Remove the outer loop you have that goes until `endNum` and it works fine. **(See my edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for (int p=0;p<=lnk.size();p++) {
    char addLet=lnk.get(p);
    String wholeWord=""+addLet;
    System.out.print(wholeWord);
}
```

to:

```
for (int p = 0;p < lnk.size();p++) {
    char addLet=lnk.get(p);
    String wholeWord=""+addLet;
    System.out.print(wholeWord);
}
```

I have removed `=` from `<=` here since if you iterate all the way till `lnk.size()`, you are going out of the bounds of the array,